# Python: How do i manipulate the list to get the string starting with '+'?

Tags: python

I am comparing 2 txt files that are `ls -R` of the etc directory in a linux system. I compared the 2 files using `difflib.differ` and got this list as my result (i put the dots to keep the list short in here):

```
result = [' etc:\n', ' ArchiveSEL\n', ' HOSTNAME\n', ' RMCPUser\n', ...,
    ' qcleaner\n', '+ extraFile\n', ' rc.d\n', '+ extraFile2\n', ...,
    ' resolv.conf\n', ' wu-ftpd\n']
```

I want to be able to take the strings with the `'+'` sign out to do something else. how do i manipulate the list? in the example above, i want to be able to get this string `"extraFile"` and `"extraFile2"`.

Thanks to all the people who posted solutions. It helps a lot and I am grateful :)

Here's what I did to get the string I wanted:

newresult = [file[2:-1] for file in result if file.startswith('+')]

to print out the strings:

for i in range (len(newresult)):
    print newresult[i]

THANKS~!!! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehension:

```
newlist = [file[1:] for file in result if file.startswith('+')]
#            ^-- gets rid of `+` at the beginning
```

See the [string methods documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

And if you want to get rid of the newline character and whitespaces just do:

```
newlist = [file[1:].strip() for file in result if file.startswith('+')]
```

---

Another way would be to use [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter), but you cannot manipulate the string then (just want to mention it for completeness):

```
newlist = filter(lambda s: s.startswith('+'), result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [x.strip('+').strip() for x in result if x.startswith("+")]
['extraFile', 'extraFile2']
```

Improved version with stripping out '+' and whitespace/linebreaks

Comment: +1 for `strip('+')` but I think even better would be to use `.strip('+ \n')` instead of two times `strip()` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try a list comprehension : `[x for x in result if x[0]=='+']`